# getdate on FreeBSD

Tags: c, open-source, freebsd, getdate

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/contrib/tar/lib/Attic/getdate.c?hideattic=0

> Revision 1.2
>   Fri Sep 15 08:04:20 2006 UTC (4 years, 11 months ago) by ru
>   Branches: MAIN
>   CVS tags: HEAD
>   FILE REMOVED
>   Changes since revision 1.1: +0 -0 lines
>
> Remove vestiges of GNU tar.

What does this mean? `getdate.c` has been moved somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means the gnu tar version has been removed from the FreeBSD source tree in favor of a BSD-licensed one aka bsdtar (which works very nicely). This means of course that it does not belong in contrib anymore and has been moved to here: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/tar/?hideattic=0